# How to avoid div wrapping and row height in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/817Lcj4d/2/

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The "content" div wraps around "sidebar", I'm trying to avoid that.

The first "row" in content takes the height of sidebar, I'm trying to avoid that as well.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what it should look like.

Comment: What do you want it to look like ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/abhighosh18/817Lcj4d/3/ : do you want this ?

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is for the content div to behave exactly the same as when you don't load Bootstrap.

Comment: Or like this way https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/817Lcj4d/5/

Comment: What do you mean by "The first "row" in content takes the height of sidebar". In my system these values are as follows . sidebar height  = 68px, content first row height : 18px.

Comment: *the content div to behave exactly the same as when you don't load* ?? @murid : please explain

Comment: You're mistaken about row height, as seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/817Lcj4d/10

Answer (score 0):

Here is updated DEMO:
https://jsfiddle.net/817Lcj4d/9/

HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#sidebar {
background: red;
  width: 15%;
  float: left;
  min-height: 100%;
}
#content {
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
  width: 85%;
}
```

Comment: thanks but that's not what I'm looking for. I want to touch CSS only to overwrite some of Bootstrap properties, not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a margin on `#content` and one fewer rows does the trick:

```
#content {
    margin-left: 115px;
}

<div id="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">content</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/817Lcj4d/11)**

If you're ok with a flexible sidebar width, just put it in the Bootstrap grid as well:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="content" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 pull-right">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">content</div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 pull-left">
            <ul>
                <li>item</li>
                <li>item</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/817Lcj4d/13)**

In response to your comment... One more level of markup and you can have all the rows you like.

**[Demo 3](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/817Lcj4d/17)**

Comment: Thanks but there are going to be several rows.

Comment: And again to make proper use of Bootstrap's container class. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/817Lcj4d/17